# Merge array with http get result rxjs angular

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

So, this is probably something very simple, but i just don't see the light.

I have a http get request with RXJS in Angular , it looks something like this in my service:

```
getData():Observable<any>{
    let url = 'http://www.randomUrl/data';

    return this.http.get(url)
        .map((res:Response)=> {let body = res.json(); return body;})
        .concatMap((data)=>this.getComputers(data))
        .concatMap((data)=>this.getComputer(data))
        .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

// The information I receive in getComputers is the next one, from which i only create a new JSON Array with numberID, computers.hostname, computers.id, and computers.installation.property1

// NOTE: There can be multiple computers under one numberId

```
[
  {
    "numberId": "948004830011",
    "computers": [
      {
        "hostname": "COMPUTER-A1",
        "id": "COMPUTER-A1",
        "installation": {
          "property1": "NONE",
          "property2": "NONE",
          "property3": "NONE"
        }
      },
...
    ]
  },
  {
    "numberId": "848004830011",
    "computers": [
      {
        "hostname": "COMPUTER-A4",
        "id": "COMPUTER-A4",
        "installation": {
          "property1": "NONE",
          "property2": "NONE",
          "property3": "NONE"
        }
      }
....
    ]
  }
]
```

//get All Computers

```
  getComputers(data): Observable<any[]> {
    let jsonArr = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      for (let j = 0; j < data[i].computers.length; j++) {
        jsonArr.push({
          number: data[i].number,
          id: data[i].computers[j].id,
          property1: data[i].computers[j].installation.property1
        });
      }
    }

    return Observable.of(jsonArr);
  }
```

//In getComputer I receive the next data:

```
  [
  {
    "number": "948004830011",
    "id": "COMPUTER-A1",
    "property1": "NONE"
  },

....

]
```

//Now, in getComputer I get more information based on the property1 of each computer, that's why i created an array observables where i could collect the http requests results and do a forkJoin at the end. This works, however, I want to include the number, id and property1 value in each one of them.

```
  getComputer(data):Observable<any[]>{
    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

//if I add the Observable of a value in the observables array, it won't separate the results from each computer, it will bring all the results separated.
    // observables.push(Observable.of(data[i].id));

        let url = 'url' + '/' + data[i].id;
       observables.push(this.http.get(url)
         .map((res: Response) => { let body = res.json().children; return body; })     
         .catch((res: Response) => Observable.of(null))
         .catch(this.handleError));
    }
    return Observable.forkJoin(observables);
  }
```

// I'm currenty receiving the next data:

```
[
// I want to add here number, hostname, and id from each computer
  [
    // computer information
  ],
  ...
  [..
    // computer information
  ],
  ...
]
```

// If i use observables.push(Observable.of(data[i].id)), I receive an array where computer id is 0 , number id is 1, computer data is 2, and then the next computer id is 3.

```
[
  "COMPUTER-A1",
  "948004830011",
  [
    // computer information
  ]
  ,
  "COMPUTER-A2",
  "948004830011",
  [
    // computer information
  ],
  "COMPUTER-A3",
  "948004830011",
  [
     // computer information
  ],
    ...
]
```

I want however, the information related to each computer in one array, that is, 
computer id will always be 0 in each array, computer number 1, and computer information 2.
How could I achieve this? I don't know the exact number of computers there exist. Is it possible to create something like the next one??

```
[
[
  "COMPUTER-A1",
  "948004830011",
  [
    // computer information
  ]
],
[
  "COMPUTER-A2",
  "948004830011",
  [
    // computer information
  ]
],

...
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would take a different approach to this, you need to know that `rxjs` and `requests` in general are `asynchronous` so don't try to make them `synchronous` if you don't have to.

For the example lets assume the response of your `http` request is

```
[
{id: "COMPUTER-A1", number: "948004830011"},
{id: "COMPUTER-A2", number: "948004830011"}
]
```

Now if you handle this data like:

```
return this.http.get(url)
        .map((res:Response)=> res.json())
        .map((data)=>data.map((d) => this.getComputersData(d)))
        .catch(this.handleError);

public getComputersData(data: any): any {
  let computersData: any = data;
  this.getComputers(computersData.number)
      .subscribe((computers) => computersData.computers = computers);
  return computersData;
}

private getComputers(computerNumber: string): Observable<any> {
  this.http.get('some/url/to/get/computers/' + computerNumber);
}
```

The final structure would look like:

```
[
  {
    id: 'COMPUTER-A1',
    number: '948004830011',
    computers: [
      // whatever data you return from getComputers()
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 'COMPUTER-A2',
    number: '948004830011',
    computers: [
      // whatever data you return from getComputers()
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: wow, you are right, I was doing extra things that made no sense at all. Thanks!

Comment: I have another question, do you know how to make an interval call using this code ?  Would something like Observable.interval(5000) work ? @Ante

Comment: @sie What kind of interval ? I assume you want to fetch new data every `X` seconds, `Observable.interval()` does something completely different and it won't do what you want. Maybe try `setInterval()` it's native javascript method ?

Comment: both work, but setInterval gave me better results. Thanks!